# How to measure the pairwise similarity between two textual data sets?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, tfidf

I have `N` textual data sets, and each one is composed of thousands of documents. I want to compare them to find which data sets are more similar (Similar to what it is done in Figure 1 of [this article](https://aclanthology.org/C18-1179.pdf).

My initial thought was to concatenate all the documents in a given data set, transforming each data set into a large document. Then, I would apply the TF-IDF vectorizer on the `N` documents. With the TF-IDF values, I could compare pairs of documents using some similarity measure, as the cosine, for example.

However, I'm struggling to find this way of summarizing my data sets without messing the data representation, more specifically the IDF value.
The IDF is computed using the `log(N)/|{d in D: t in d}|`, where `N` is the number of documents in the data set.

The problem is that, for comparing only two data sets (`A` and `B`), first I have to concatenate all the documents in `A`, and in `B`, generating documents `doc_A` and `doc_B`, respectively. Then, I apply the TF-IDF vectorizer in `[doc_A,doc_B]`. But, for a word `w` that appears quite frequently in many documents of `A`, but in only one document of `B`, my `IDF(w)` would be `log(2/2)=0`.

That seems conceptually wrong. Any ideas on a better way to do these comparisons?

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. I don't understand what is the problem with the first solution. You know that you must represent represent all the documents with the same vocabulary right?

Comment: @Erwan As I'm using TF-IDF, for `#classes=3`, the max. document frequency would be 3. That does not represent my whole dataset, which has more than 20k documents.

Comment: I don't understand, what do you call `#classes`? I don't think it's related to TFIDF.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that by transforming the data sets into documents would mess my IDF value. The IDF is computed using the log(N)/|{d in D: t in d}|, where N is the number of documents in the data set.  

For example: I have only two data sets (A and B) and I want to compare them. First, I concatenate all the documents in A, and in B, generating documents doc_A and doc_B, respectively. Then, I apply the TF-IDF vectorizer in [doc_A,doc_B]. If the word `w` appears quite frequently in many documents of A, but in only one document of B, my `IDF(w)` would be `log(2/2)=0`.

Comment: That's clearer but I'm still not sure exactly what you want to obtain. it looks like the last step is wrong because you actually provide 2 documents to TFIDFVectorizer instead of providing all the docs in A and all the docs in B, i.e. the full list of documents. This would give you regular TFIDF vectors over the whole data. In case you want to obtain the IDF independently on each dataset, you could first obtain the global vocabulary on the whole data, for example using `CountVectorizer` (that's probably not the most efficient way but it's simple), then use `TfidfVectorizer` on every dataset...

Comment: ... independently but providing the global vocabulary obtained in the first step (through the `vocabulary` parameter). However I'm not sure that this option is very good, because you would be comparing TFIDF with different IDF weights and that could cause some bias.

Comment: @Erwan, Thank you for replying. And yes, I have the same feeling about the last step in my solution, and this is the central point of my question here. I'm not sure about how to compare different data sets using the same fitted vectorizer. So far, your first suggestion seems the most reasonable to me. I.e., providing the full list of documents to the `TFIDFVectorizer` and then using the `transform` method only on a document composed of all the texts in a given data set...

Comment: ... In fact, I don't know if I wasn't able to correctly identify similar problems on the internet. If you have other suggestions about how solving this issue, I'd be glad to hear them.

Comment: Maybe you're overthinking this. I think the standard, most basic method would be to represent all the documents from both A and B as TFIDF vector, i.e. using the same vocabulary and IDF weights. This option is not perfect of course since it doesn't take into account the possible IDF differences between the datasets, but i don't think there's a perfect solution anyway.

Comment: @Erwan thank you for the fruitful discussion. I guess I'm overthinking this indeed.